# creating an eviroment with venv and python 2.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-venv

conda user here. I would like to create an environment with the Python builtin *venv* environment tool. 
I would like to set up an environment including python 2.7

Is that possible with venv? I have not seen any example yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible with the stdlib [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to target a different runtime.

Use [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) instead.

Comment: Thanks. Keep healthy.

Answer (score 1):

From this [blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-python-versions-and-virtual-environments-venv-pyenv-pyvenv-a29fb00c296f/):

> ... , venv is limited to versions of Python greater than 3.3

We have to use either pyenv or virtualenv (probably there are others e.g., conda).